# Inverse chinese theorem $x \in Qr(n) \iff x \in Qr(p) \wedge x \in Qr( q)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem, quadratic-residues

I found this sentence in a paper :
Let $n=pq$ where $p, q$ are primes and let $Qr(n) = \{x^2 \mod n | \; x \in Z_n^*\}$ the set of quadratic residues in $Z^*_n$.
By Chinese remainder theorem we get :$$x \in Qr(n) \iff x \in Qr(p) \wedge x \in Qr( q)$$
It is not obvious to me why it holds. This is my effort to prove the first direction:
$x \in Q(n) \implies \exists a \in Z_n^*:\; x = a^2 \mod n$
Now I am trying to use something like inverse chinese remainder:
If $x \in Qr(p) \implies \exists b \in Z_p\; : x = b^2 \mod p$
and if  $x \in Qr(p) \implies \exists b' \in Z_q\; : x = b'^2 \mod q$
Applying CRT:
$$x = b^2\frac{p}{pq}N_1 + b'^2\frac{q}{pq}N_2$$
where $N_1\frac{1}{q} = 1 \mod p \wedge N_2 \frac{1}{p} = 1\mod q$
I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Apply the Remark in the linked dupe to the polynomial $\,f(x) = x^2 - k\ \ $

Comment: I checked the link . Do you suggest considering $f(x) = x^2 -a$ and solving it in $Z_n$ which   would be the same  as solving $f(x) = 0$ in $Z_p$ and $Z_q$ ? But why is that? This looks like an inverse chinese remainder

Comment: As in the link, suppose $a$ is a square mod $p$ & $q$, so $\,a\equiv r^2\pmod{\!p},\, a\equiv s^2\pmod{\!q}$. By CRT there is an integer $x$ with $\,x\equiv r\pmod{\!p}$ & $\,x\equiv s\pmod{\!q}\,$ so $\,x^2\equiv r^2\equiv a\pmod{\!p},\,$ and $\,x^2\equiv r^2\equiv a\pmod{\!p},\,$ so $\,x^2\equiv a\pmod{\!p\ \&\ q}\Rightarrow x^2\equiv a\pmod{\!pq}$ by $p,q$ coprime & CRT, therefore  $\,a\,$ is a square mod $pq\ \ $